# ul#menu vs #menu?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

**HTML**:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="" class="active">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Testimonials</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Request a Quote</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**:

```
ul#menu li {
    display:inline;
    margin-left:12px;
}
```

Is there a difference between using "`ul#menu li`" and just "`#menu li`"?  I used both versions and they seem to accomplish the same thing.  Is there a reason why most tutorials use add the "ul" before the id?

Comment: It all boils down to specificity. Some good links: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/specificity, http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/ and, http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is one obvious difference and one more subtle difference.

The obvious difference is that `#menu` targets all elements with the ID `#menu`, whereas `ul#menu` only targets `ul` elements. If you only give the ID `#menu` to `ul` elements, the selectors will always have the same result.

There is one potential difference with something called specificity. This is a way of determining which rule to use in case of conflicts. So if you have these two rules:

```css
#menu li {color: blue;}
ul#menu li {color: red;}
```

the second rule will win, because it is more specific, and the text will be red. The rules for specificity are complex and not always intuitive, but in this case the simple result is that `ul#menu li` is slightly more specific than `#menu li`. If you only have one stylesheet, this is unlikely to be an issue for you. If you have several stylesheets, it can be confusing to work out why a certain rule is being ignored; specificity is often the answer.

As to why most tutorials use `ul#menu`, I don't know. (In fact, I only have your assertion as evidence that they do!) My guess is that they are making things Really Very Obvious for the sake of idiot readers.

Comment: shouldn't the correct syntax be "#menu ul li"  why does the "ul" come before the selector?

Comment: @anc1revv Because the ul itself has the id `menu`. `#menu ul li` means `li` elements within a `ul` element that is within another element that has the id `menu`.

Answer (score 3):

The results rendered will not be different for those specific elements.

However, `ul#menu li` is more specific, as it targets all elements of type `li` with parent id `#menu` and type `ul`.

- Imagine the selector like UL > #MENU > LI

`#menu li` only targets all elements of type `li` with parent id `#menu`.

- Imagine the selector like #MENU > LI

For most purposes, they will do exactly the same thing. `#menu li` should not have any effect on other elements on the page, as id is specific, and therefore, as suggested in the comments below, it is unnecessary. As such, I would stick to `#menu li`.

Comment: ul#menu is more expensive as it will attempt to determine if #menu is a UL after grabbing that element by ID, which you won't need to do as IDs on elements should be unique in your document. You're making a more specific selector that doesn't need to be that specific and will take longer to match.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is specificity. The `ul#menu` is more specific and deems that the element the rule targets must be a `<ul>` that has an id of menu. Say you change your `<ul>` to a `<div>` that has an id of menu it wouldn't work (without changing your css). Also if you define something with just `#menu` you can add overrides by making the rule more specific by using `ul#menu`. You can read more here: [battle-of-the-selectors-specificity](http://3nhanced.com/css/battle-of-the-selectors-specificity/).

Answer (score 0):

The difference in specificity between the two will not often make a difference, but we could think of circumstances in which it will.

What if you have `<div id="menu"></div>` on one page and `<ul id="menu"></ul>` on another, and you are using the same CSS file in both? I'm not saying that would be a good design decision, but in that circumstance the distinction between `ul#menu` and `#menu` would be important. Do you want the CSS to apply to all elements with `id="menu"` or only `ul` elements with `id="menu"`? That's the distinction.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to give the same answer as @jacktheripper, but want to add the following:

Yes, `ul#menu li` is more specific, but it also requires more parsing time, as CSS reads the selectors from right to left. So it picks out all elements `#menu` and afterwards gather all `UL`-lists and from those select the ones, which contain the previously found `#menu`.

This makes more difference when using long chains of selectors: `#mainmenu ul.menu li.current ul li.current` (instead of maybe `#mainmenu .current .current`).